# I am using ocrmypdf for converting the scanned pdf to searchable pdf. I am getting the dependency error of jbig2 and pngquant - "was not found"

Tags: pdf-extraction, jbig2, ocrmypdf

I am trying convert scanned pdf into searchable pdf using ocrmypdf. In few cases its throwing the error of
The output file size is 21.93× larger than the input file.
Possible reasons for this include:
--deskew was issued, causing transcoding.
The optional dependency 'jbig2' was not found, so some image optimizations could not be attempted.
The optional dependency 'pngquant' was not found, so some image optimizations could not be attempted.

I am using python virtual environment. pngquant already installed. Not able to install jbig2. I need to set deskew as True. How can I resolve the dependency?

how can I install the dependencies